# Jest & material-ui: how to test presence of a specific icon?

Tags: material-ui

I recently migrated an app to mui v4, which I love.

Also done is updating our test suite that runs with jest/enzyme. For example I now favor `mount` instead of `shallow`.

**One problem is that I cannot find a way to test icons presence.**

*I am using all latest version of material-ui, react and tooling like jest/enzyme, etc, at the time of writing*

---

[In MUI source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/58bebd747f8a4cb757b2f05321d56f25bb04821e/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/TabScrollButton.test.js#L56), I see things like this in the spec files:

```js
wrapper.find('svg[data-mui-test="KeyboardArrowLeftIcon"]'
```

Here is in [createSvgIcon](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9259aaaebbeded8b9b538a37c4be6094baede348/packages/material-ui-icons/src/utils/createSvgIcon.js#L7) source how this prop declared:

```
<SvgIcon {...props} data-mui-test={`${displayName}Icon`} ref={ref}>
```

HOWEVER, I cannot find any reference to that `data-mui-test` prop in my own `node_modules` file in `@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon.js`:

```js
var Component = _react.default.memo(_react.default.forwardRef(function (props, ref) {
  return _react.default.createElement(_SvgIcon.default, (0, _extends2.default)({
    ref: ref
  }, props), path);
}));
```

And, as a matter of fact, `wrapper.debug()` in the tests shows that the prop is absent from the DOM:

```
[...]
<svg 
  className="MuiSvgIcon-root" 
  focusable="false" 
  viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
  color={[undefined]} 
  aria-hidden="true" 
  role="presentation">
[...]
```

---

**Questions**

1. Why is `data-mui-test` prop is removed from generated npm module code?
2. Is this still the right way to test icons presence? ([as suggested here by mui team member](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15928#issuecomment-497634585))

Answer (score 1):

To better mimic the user experience in accessing the icon, use the `titleAccess` prop: (replace `SvgIcon` with the icon that you are actually using)

```
<SvgIcon titleAccess="My Icon" />
```

Then in test:

```
expect(screen.getByTitle("My Icon")).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Reference: https://tech.8hobbies.com/posts/test-presence-of-material-ui-icon/

Answer (score 0):

The standard testing technique of data-testid works for these icons, i.e.:

```
<Warning color="warning" data-testid="warning-icon" />
```

Then in your test

```
expect(documentBody.getByTestId('warning-icon')).toBeInTheDocument();
```