# Testing specific MaterialUI Icon

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

Is it possible to test in specific Material UI icon as ArrowLeft / ArrowRight instead of .MuiSvgIcon-root?

App component:

```
return {open ? <ArrowLeft/> :<ArrowRight/>}
```

RTL Testing : Below tests are passing but it doesn't check in specific ArrowLeft or ArrowRight icon.

```
describes("MockTest",()=>{

it("renders Left arrow",()=>{
const {container} = renders(<App open={true}/>);
expect(container.querySelector(".MuiSvgIcon-root").toBeTruthy();
});

it("renders Right arrow",()=>{
const {container} = renders(<App open={false}/>);
expect(container.querySelector(".MuiSvgIcon-root").toBeTruthy();
});

});
```

Comment: similar thread [jest-material-ui-how-to-test-presence-of-a-specific-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805601/jest-material-ui-how-to-test-presence-of-a-specific-icon)

Answer (score 3):

Was able to test this by rendering the Material UI icon, grabbing the inner html, then comparing it to my components icon.

```
const { container } = render(<ArrowRight />);
const iconHtml = container.innerHTML;
cleanup();

const { container } = renders(<App open={false}/>);
expect(
    container.querySelector(".MuiSvgIcon-root").innerHTML
).toEqual(iconHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for the RTL package. Check this [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering#without-shallow-rendering) post by the author of the RTL package.

RTL **DOES NOT** support shallow rendering. So the `ArrowLeft` and `ArrowRight` will always be rendered.